# How to disable PodSecurityPolicy warning?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, rancher, podsecuritypolicy

I am trying to understand where is this warning coming from ? I have disabled the PSP support in my cluster and indeed using k8s version lower than 1.25. But I want to understand and disable this warning. Is it possible ? Which controller is responsible to handle this WARNING?

```
kubectl get psp -A
Warning: policy/v1beta1 PodSecurityPolicy is deprecated in v1.21+, unavailable in v1.25+
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a blog K8s where various aspects of the topic "Warnings" are explained.
https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/09/03/warnings/#deprecation-warnings

In summary, these have been introduced since version 1.19 and you can’t remove them easily (unless you use the k8s.io/client-go library to modify the K8s API).
https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/09/03/warnings/#customize-client-handling

The last resort might be to "throw away" the output:

```
kubectl get psp -A 2>&1 | grep -vi "warn" | grep -vi "deprecat"
```